# Как правильно перезаписать dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, dict

Есть такой код:

```
list_info = []
dict_info = {}
for item_order in result_get_order:
    if item_order['status'] == 'processing':
        dict_info['id'] = item_order['id']
        dict_info['date_created'] = item_order['date_created']
        dict_info['total'] = item_order['total']
        dict_info['customer_ip_address'] = item_order['customer_ip_address']
        dict_info['customer_user_agent'] = item_order['customer_user_agent']
        dict_info['customer_note'] = item_order['customer_note']
        for item_metadata in item_order['meta_data']:
            if item_metadata['key'] == 'billing_str_vk':
                dict_info['billing_str_vk'] = item_metadata['value']
            if item_metadata['key'] == 'billing_name':
                dict_info['billing_name'] = item_metadata['value']
            if item_metadata['key'] == 'billing_fam':
                dict_info['billing_fam'] = item_metadata['value']
            if item_metadata['key'] == 'billing_otch':
                dict_info['billing_otch'] = item_metadata['value']
        list_info.append(dict_info)
        dict_info.clear()

print(list_info)
```

По итогу его выполнения список **list_info** - пустой.
Если убираю строку dict_info.clear() , то в списке появляются повторяющиеся значения.

Цель: получать данные по клиентам и записывать dict в list.
Хотелось бы иметь на выходе: 
[{'id': 92}, {'id': 93}, {'id': 94}], но сейчас получается либо, 
[{}, {}, {}] либо - 
[{'id': 92}, {'id': 92}, {'id': 92}]

Вопрос: как исправить ситуацию?
Возможно, вы знаете лучший способ организации этого процесса. Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: перенесите строку `dict_info = {}` внутрь цикла - первой строкой в цикле, а `dict_info.clear()` - удалите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu Благодарю, работает. Оформите ответ и я его отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перенести строку:

```
dict_info = {}
```

внутрь цикла в качестве первой строки тела цикла или первой строкой в теле `if item_order['status'] == 'processing'` и удалить строку `dict_info.clear()`, то ваше решение должно правильно отрабатывать.